# Can we give posttest without having pretest?

Tags: definition

The Merriam-Webster Dictionary defined posttest as a test often used in conjunction with a pretest. The dictionary used "often", so can we give posttest without having a pretest?

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/posttest

Answer (score 1):

By definition no. Post means after, so refers to a test done after another one. That does not mean one might not do the same thing without a pre-test, but one would not call it a post-test and it would no longer have the same properties that the two steps have in combination.